# Implement UDP network discovery in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sockets, udp

I'm trying to implement a UDP broadcast/response network discovery protocol in PowerShell.  I have found a few examples of doing this in C#, but I'm having trouble translating into PowerShell.

The protocol is pretty simple:

1. Send broadcast from port x to port x.
2. Nodes reply to port x with payload.
3. Parse sender IP addresses to build list.

So far, I have part of the broadcast working.  I can send to the appropriate port, but I haven't had any luck defining the origination port.  I know it's working because I see the responses in Wireshark.  I've tabled changing the origination port for now.  I'm trying to get the chunk of code for receive started, and I'm stuck trying to translate C# code.  I'm guessing that Power Shell can do this (because it's very similar to C#), but I haven't seen it said for sure anywhere.

C# examples ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832770/sending-udp-broadcast-receiving-multiple-messages), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852781/c-sharp-how-to-do-network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast), [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/ReceiveBroadcast.htm), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746519/udpclient-receive-on-broadcast-address), [example](https://pshscripts.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/send-udpdatagramps1.html)), VB.NET [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276417/udpclient-begin-received-packet-source-address), Java [Example](https://michieldemey.be/blog/network-discovery-using-udp-broadcast/).

I started to try to convert this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450216/2484483) (with some of [this](https://pshscripts.blogspot.co.uk/2008/12/send-udpdatagramps1.html)) from C# and I'm getting runtime errors (code here):

```
$Enc      = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII 
$Message = "WPPS" *10 
$responseData   = $Enc.GetBytes( $Message ) 

#$responseData = [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCIIGetBytes("someData");

while (1)
{
    $server = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient(1047);
    $clientEp = New-Object System.Net.IPEndPoint(0.0.0.0, 1047);
    $clientRequestData = server.Receive(ref $clientEp);
    $clientRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString($clientRequestData);

    Console.WriteLine($"Recived {$clientRequest} from {$clientEp.Address}, sending response: {$responseData}");
    $server.Send($responseData, $responseData.Length, $clientEp);
    $server.Close();
}
```

When I try to run the above code, I get repeating errors below.  I'm sure it's a disparity between C# and PowerShell syntax, but I have almost no idea what it could be.  I'm not sure if that first error is after the first iteration loop, or on the first iteration.  It looks like after.

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network 
address/port) is normally permitted"
At line:9 char:15
+     $server = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient(1047);
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: address"
At line:10 char:17
+     $clientEp = New-Object System.Net.IPEndPoint(0.0.0.0, 1047);
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

ref : The term 'ref' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:11 char:41
+     $clientRequestData = server.Receive(ref $clientEp);
+                                         ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ref:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Encoding.ASCII.GetString : The term 'Encoding.ASCII.GetString' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, 
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:12 char:22
+     $clientRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString($clientRequestData);
+                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Encoding.ASCII.GetString:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

$Recived {$clientRequest} from {$clientEp.Address}, sending response: {$responseData} : The term '$Recived {$clientRequest} from 
{$clientEp.Address}, sending response: {$responseData}' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:14 char:23
+ ... e.WriteLine($"Recived {$clientRequest} from {$clientEp.Address}, send ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($Recived {$clie...{$responseData}:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Exception calling "Send" with "3" argument(s): "A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not 
connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied"
At line:15 char:5
+     $server.Send($responseData, $responseData.Length, $clientEp);
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SocketException
```

Are there any examples of how to do this in Power Shell?  Can Power Shell actually do this?

I know a couple things in Power Shell, but almost nothing about C#.

Comment: Why don't you `AddType` around the C# code? I mean, what's the value you're expecting from converting this to native PowerShell?

Comment: Because I didn't know such a thing existed until you mentioned it.  It looks like `Add-Type` lets you import C# resources.  I'm not sure how importing resources will assist me in this case.  I know a couple things in Power Shell, but almost nothing about C# (just that it's Microsoft's evolution of Java and .NET, or something).